# Get latitude and longitude from the address with mapbox

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, mapbox

Does anyone have an example of how to get the latitude and longitude of an address using the mapbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Mapbox Android SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#geocoder) guide, do the following:

Don't execute any of the example code on the main UI thread.

**Example 1:**

Please note that the `position` **parameter is optional** but will make getting results quicker.

```
// position used for proximity
Position position = Position.fromCoordinates(-73.98572, 40.74843);

MapboxGeocoding client = new MapboxGeocoding.Builder()
            .setAccessToken("<your access token here>")
            .setLocation("Empire State Building")
            .setProximity(position)
            .build();

Response<GeocodingResponse> response = client.execute();
```

**Example 2:**

```
MapboxGeocoding client = new MapboxGeocoding.Builder()
            .setAccessToken("<your access token here>")
            .setLocation("Empire State Building")
            .build();

Response<GeocodingResponse> response = client.execute();
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what I want. I own the address and want the coordinates it. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: Those co-ordinates supplied are too narrow down the search for the address

Comment: Clive is correct in that the coordinates are used to bias results. It is an optional parameter but will make getting results quicker. For a full example on how to use our geocoder in your Android app first, include the Mapbox Android Services SDK in your `build.gradle` and follow this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/geocoding/)

Comment: Thanks @cammace - I will update my answer with your comment regarding the optional parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a `Mapbox.GeocodingBuilder`, get a `Response`, and access the field you want from the `Response`.

Here is a simple example I found online and edited slightly.

```
private void simpleSample() {
    MapboxGeocoder client = new MapboxGeocoder.Builder()
            .setAccessToken(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN)
            .setLocation("The White House")
            .build();

    client.enqueue(new Callback<GeocoderResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<GeocoderResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            // Features, basically, is a list of search results
            // get the first one
            // get latitude and longitude
            String latitude = response.body().getFeatures().get(0).getLatitude();
            String longitude = response.body().getFeatures().get(0).getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // log t.getMessage()
        }
    });
}
```

You can read some basics about the mapbox Geocoding API on their [API 101 webpage](https://www.mapbox.com/help/geocoding-service/).

You can see some official examples on the [mapbox Geocoding API documentation page](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=Java#search-for-places)

You can try search terms and see results on a map or as raw JSON — which is useful for seeing the shape of the results data and how to traverse it — on the [API forward geocoding playground page](https://www.mapbox.com/api-playground/#/forward-geocoding/?_k=6e2wob) (note: you must sign in to a mapbox account to do this, but making one is free if you don't have one).

(Full disclosure: I worked for SmartyStreets, an address verification and autocompletion company, with [competing products](https://smartystreets.com/products/single-address).)